# Method of 'Table' of object 'Shape' Failed - PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have some code that takes values from an excel worksheet and pastes them into a powerpoint.  I then want to format those values:

```
    Dim shp as PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim tbl as Table
    Dim shp_count as Long

    sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteHTML, DisplayAsIcon:=msoFalse
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    shp_count = sld.Shapes.Count

    Set shp = sld.Shapes(sld.Shapes.Count)
    shp.Name = key & "_Header"
    Set tbl = shp.Table
    With tbl.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
        .Font.Color = vbWhite
        .Characters(1, 11).Font.Bold = msoFalse
    End With
```

As a note, this particular shape being pasted into the powerpoint is just one cell.

When I run this on my own, it works fine.  However, when another user tries to run the exact same code on their machine, I get a "Method of 'Table' of object 'Shape' Failed" error.  Any idea why or better ways to go about doing this?

Comment: What does `Debug.Print shp.HasTable` return?

Comment: @BigBen it is returning -1

Comment: What does it return on the other user's machine?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe other user's PC is not that quick as yours and pasting the shape gets more time?
Try maybe to add

```
  DoEvents
```

Before the line:

```
  Set tbl = shp.Table
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this!